# print function in linked list is not giving error or output. What is the wrong implementation?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename type_t>
struct linked_node {
    type_t data;
    linked_node * next;
    linked_node * prev;
};


template <typename type_t>
class list {
public:
    linked_node<type_t> datum;
    linked_node<type_t> * head, * tail;

    list() {datum.next = datum.prev = head = tail = NULL;}

    list<type_t> &push_back(type_t);
    type_t pop_back();

    list<type_t> &push_front(type_t);
    type_t pop_front();

    void print();
};

template <typename type_t>
void list<type_t>::print(){
    if(!head) throw std::out_of_range("Empty list");
    linked_node<type_t> * ptr = head;

    while(ptr){
        std:: cout << ptr->data << " ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
        std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename type_t>
list<type_t> &list<type_t>::push_back(type_t value){
    linked_node<type_t> * item = new linked_node<type_t>;
    if(!item) throw std::bad_alloc();

    item->data = value;

    if(tail){
        item->prev = tail;
        tail->next = item;
    }

    tail = item;

    if(!head) head = tail;
    return *this;
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t list<type_t>::pop_back(){
    if(!head) throw std::out_of_range("empty list");

    linked_node<type_t> * item;
    type_t value;

    if(head != tail && tail){
        value = tail->data;
        item = tail;
        tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next = NULL;
        delete item;
    return value;
    }

    value = head->data;
    delete head;
    delete tail;
    head = tail = NULL;

    return value;
}

template <typename type_t>
list<type_t> &list<type_t>::push_front(type_t value){
    linked_node<type_t> * item = new linked_node<type_t>;
    if(!item) throw std::bad_alloc();

    item->data = value;

    if(head){
        item->next = head;
        head->prev = item;
    }
    head = item;
    if(!tail) tail = head;
    return *this;
}

template <typename type_t>
type_t list<type_t>::pop_front(){
    if(!head) throw std::out_of_range("Empty list");

    linked_node<type_t> * item;
    type_t value;

    if (head != tail && head){
        value = head->data;
        item = head;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head = head->next;
        delete item;

        return value;
    }

    value = tail->data;
    delete tail;
    delete head;
    head = tail = NULL;

    return value;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

    list<int> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(5).push_back(13).push_front(22);

    numbers.print();


    return 0;
}
```

Above i just wanted to print all elements from begining to end just to test if its working.

When i use like the code below, it is working perfectly.

```
linked_node<int> ptr = numbers.head;
cout << ptr->data << " ";
ptr = ptr->next;
cout << ptr->data << " ";
ptr = ptr->next;
cout << ptr->data << " ";
ptr = ptr->next;
```

But when want to iterate as if it is in print() func. nothing happens (no errors or no outputs). i can't solve or see the problem

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Tons of people have asked questions here about their implementations of linked lists. Look around and I'm sure you'll find some ideas to help you debug your own problem.

Comment: It's working here: http://ideone.com/3g1bV5

Comment: I can see that `std::cout << std::endl;` in `print()` has different indentation than all other lines in your code. Maybe you added that line when posting this question here? If that is the case then that might be your problem. If the code that you tested didn't have it and your terminal have line buffered stdout you might not see any output.

Comment: @gurka i am using eclipse can it be a problem of ide?

Comment: `((((ptr)->prev))->next) Error: Failed to execute MI command: -var-update 1 var4 Error message from debugger back end: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf011` 

in debug mode having an error like this.

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran That error is a result of pointer mismanagement on your part.  And "learning the basics" should include how to properly write classes that manage memory, including copying and destruction.

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran `linked_node<type_t> * item = new linked_node<type_t>; if(!item) throw std::bad_alloc();` -- Also this can never happen with a standard ANSI C++ compiler.  If `new` fails, itself throws the exception.  There is no need for your code to be checking for a null pointer and throwing the exception -- the code will never reach the `if` statement if there is an issue with `new`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i don't even write or use something like `((((ptr)->prev))->next)`. And interesting part it's working here [link](http://ideone.com/3g1bV5)

Comment: When using `linked_node<int> *ptr = numbers.head;` instead of `linked_node<int> ptr = numbers.head;` in the `main()`, I get the same output of `print()`... `22 5 13 `. What is the problem ?

Comment: `linked_node` has no constructor to NULL `prev` and `next` pointers. Nowhere in `push_back` do I see any `prev` and `next` pointers being NULLed. You might want to start there because otherwise stuff like `while(ptr)` is doomed.